# Check if screen width is longer than height & vice versa - Can it be done?

Tags: css, orientation, screen-orientation

So I've done a fair bit of reading on media queries and I get why for most situations just specifying a dimension and going after a device might be useful... But what if you're just looking for whether the device is portrait or landscape?

What I really want is to be able to check if the screen whether the width or height is longest, and then run different CSS depending on the answer. Ideally I want to be able to do this all inline rather than running different external stylesheets.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: yes, next question.  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3889591/Detect-and-Set-the-iPhone--iPads-Viewport-Orientation-Using-JavaScript-CSS-and-Meta-Tags.htm

Comment: Have you tried using orientation?  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan and Cimmanon said, yes, it can be done. Media queries have a nifty little option called [orientation](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/the_orientation.html), which you can set to "portrait" or "landscape".

Do keep in mind, though, that not all devices/browsers support some or any media queries, so make sure you have some default styles set up for those that would ignore your styles otherwise.